# Сравнить с массивом и вывести значение по ключу

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

помогите решить задачу не пойму как в этом массиве

str = {"0":"Новый","1":"Оставил сообщение","2":"Перезвонить позже","3":"Смотреть комментарии","4":"Обработан/продажа","5":"Откланен/отказ","6":"Недоступен"}

Найти значение по соответствию ключу переменной status, например в переменной стоит 5 и чтобы вывело "Отклонен/отказ".

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str[status]

Думаю, вам не помешает ознакомиться с [начальным уроком по объектам.](http://learn.javascript.ru/object)

Цитата из этого учебника: 
Существует альтернативный синтаксис работы со свойствами, использующий квадратные скобки объект['свойство']:

```
var person = {};
person['name'] = 'Вася'; // то же что и person.name
alert(person['name']);
delete person['name'];
```

В квадратные скобки можно передать переменную:
obj[key] использует значение переменной key в качестве имени свойства:

```
var person = { age: 25 };
var key = 'age';
alert(person[key]);  // выведет person['age']
```

Записи person['age'] и person.age идентичны. С другой стороны, если имя свойства хранится в переменной (var key = "age"), то единственный способ к нему обратиться — квадратные скобки person[key].

Comment: спасибо. все понятно.